# Can't join Age of Empires III games

Tags: technical-issues, age-of-empires-iii

I recently purchased a copy of Age of Empires 3 but I have been unable to get it to connect to my friend's game via Tunngle or Hamachi. The strange thing is that I am able to see his game, but when I click join nothing happens. There are no errors or anything so I have nothing to go by. However, my friend can't see a game I host. I've spent hours trying to get this going and am fed up. I experience the exact same problem with Age of Mythology.

Comment: Sounds like a router issue with incorrect port forwarding; check if your router or firewall isn't the problem (also should include network-related info in the question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a legal copy, then the only reason I can think off is a router /
firewall problem.

**Router problem**
First, you have to check what port AoE III / AoM runs on, once you found this port you have to forward the port on your router.

I looked up the ports of AoE III / AoM for you, and came up with:
AoE III: port 2300-2310 on both TCP and UDP.
AoM: port 28800-28805 on TCP and 2300-2400, 6073 on UDP.

To forward the port you can pick the router you are using from the list **[here](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/routerindex.htm)** and then follow the guide.

If it still didnt work correctly, we got to check the firewall

**Firewall problem**
This **[link](http://www.technipages.com/blockunblock-programs-in-windows-firewall.html)** has a great way of learning you how to (un)block a program for your firewall.
Make sure AoE III / AoM isn't blocked!